# Spring AMQP - return the message back to the beginning of the queue

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I would like to know if there is any way to return message back to its original place in queue. For example, let's say we have this ordering:

`A-B-C-D` with `A` being the head and `D` being the tail. Normally, when we use `nack` or `reject` with `requeue=true`, it simply enqueues the message after the current tail. In this case, when `A` is requeued, the new ordering becomes `B-C-D-A`. However, I wonder if there's any way to enqueue to the beginning of the queue. So, if `A` is "sent back", it would be placed at the beginning of the queue, in its original place.

I search for a solution using Spring AMQP.

Comment: That's not how AMQP queues work. And why do you need this behaviour?

Comment: I know that's not the natural way they behave. And the reason I want to do it is that I need to follow a strict ordering in processing messages. For example, "follow X" and "unfollow X" messages should be processed exactly the way they have been sent. I don't want to process "unfollow" first. So, let's say when database is down while processing the message, I normally send `nack` or `reject` with `requeue=true` and this ruins the order. I can solve this issue on my own. But I was looking for something maybe supported by Spring or Rabbit out of the box. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The consumer schould `nack` the `unfollow` message if no corresponding `follow` message has been seen. This would restore the natural order.

Comment: That requires database check. For example, if `follow` and `unfollow` have been sent in very small time interval, then your suggestion may work. But if there's a month between these 2. There won't be any corresponding `follow`, we have to check database for that. `Follow/unfollow` was just an example by the way. Cases can be more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the prefetch (qos) to 1. Otherwise any prefetched messages will be delivered before the redelivery of A.

It will, however, impact performance.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you talking about `setPrefetchCount` in ListenerContainer? I mean, should I use it to set the prefetch count? Because if yes, I have already done that. The issue is that when I nack the message, because of database unavailability, it requeues the message to the end of the queue. I want it to return wherever it belongs, head of the queue. I hope I haven't misunderstood your solution.

Comment: It will go to the head of the queue and will be redelivered immediately, as long as the `prefetchCount` is 1. If the prefetch count is > 1, you will get other prefetched messages before the requeued one. A long time ago (many years) RabbitMQ used to requeue at the tail instead of the head but it was changed to requeue at the head.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks @Gary Russell. One question tho. So `prefetchCount=1`, and we `nack` the message and requeue it, it will be redelivered. Does that mean, it can potentially get stuck in a loop, if we always send `nack`?

Comment: Yes, of course. If the messages have a unique messageId property, you can use a stateful retry interceptor and give up after some number of retries. See the reference manual.

Comment: It's in `manual` acknowledgement mode, so as far as I remember, retry interceptors work only in `auto` mode. Also, could you please reference any kind of source about this : `RabbitMQ used to requeue at the tail instead of the head but it was changed to requeue at the head` if possible? Unfortunately, I couldn't find it.

Comment: I don't remember; sometime between 2010 (when I started working with it) and 2013 [when I answered this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235818/re-queue-amqp-message-at-tail-of-queue). I suspect it was closer to 2010 than 2013.

Comment: Anyways, thank you so much for the help, @Gary Russell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195837/discussion-between-mensur-qulami-and-gary-russell).